# What's the best source characterizing proteolysis cleavage sites in the phagolysosome?

Tags: molecular-biology, immunology, database, proteomics

I have found [MEROPS](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/merops/) and [TopFIND](http://clipserve.clip.ubc.ca/topfind) via the survey paper [Quantitative proteomics and terminomics to elucidate the role of ubiquitination and proteolysis in adaptive immunity](http://rsta.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/374/2079/20150372). These look like a good start, but I'm wondering whether there's anything more specific.

Ideally, I'd like a list of human phagolysosomic enzymes and some sort of statistical characterization of their cleavage sites, such as position-specific scoring matrices.

Comment: You can try [UniProt](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=locations%3A%28location%3A%22Lysosome+%5BSL-0158%5D%22%29+AND+goa%3A%28%22protease+activity+%5B0008233%5D%22%29&sort=score&=locations&=locations&=location&=any&=&=AND&=goa&=any&=AND&=content.search) to get a list. They seem to give cleavage sites for proteases, though nothing of the statistics you're looking for.

Comment: Looking at the [first entry on the list](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q8NBP7), I think those are sites at which the  subject protein is cleaved, not its substrates.

Comment: Some of the entries do contain the cleavage site for the protease, but I guess not all of them. Anyways, that list was just a thought I had… it may have been a bad one.